# passing command line options having multiple suboptions to python script -- shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have the following options:

```
python runscript.py -O start -a "-a "\"-o \\\"-f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8\\\" -l test -p maim\""
```

runscript takes `-O` and `-a` and then sends remaining to shell script 1

shell script 1 takes option -a and should consider remaining `\"-o \\\"-f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8\\\" -l test -p maim\"` as argument to shell script 2

shell script 2 takes argument `-o`, `-l` and `-p`.

Can anyone please help me with this kind of scenario. I am stuck where shell script 1 considers and starts parsing argument -o too.

Is there a simple way to do. The hierarchy of shell script 1 calling 2 should be maintained.

Regards
Sai

Answer (score 0):

The command you gave is bit confusing. I am generalizing the scenario. Is this something you meant?

`python runscript.py -p1 v1 -p2 v2 -p3 v3`

1. `runscript.py` will take all given parameters.
2. and calls `shellsript_1.sh` with selected params say `-p2 v2`
3. and then calls `shellscript_2.sh` with remaining params say `-p3 v3`

We may need more accurate explanation of the problem.

Comment: Yeah Pradip, the one which you have mentioned is right but let me be more clear with the options because some of them are kind of strings.

Comment: -O start -a "-a "\"-o \\\"-f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8\\\" -l test -p maim\""               so runscript.py based on option -O and -a would consider starting the shellscript_1.sh and provides the input with the remaining: "-a "\"-o \\\"-f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8\\\" -l test -p maim\"". shellscript_1 would take -a as the option and feed the remaining as a string "\"-o \\\"-f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8\\\" -l test -p maim\"" to shellscript_2.sh. Now shellscript_2.sh would consider -O and take "-f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8", -l as test and -p as maim and compute. This is the desired result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to do this in UNIX is to split the argument list about a pivot (usually --) such that the main script consumes all the arguments to the left of the pivot and leaves the remaining arguments for the other script(s).  If you have flexibility in your calling function, I'd recommend doing it this way.

So, if runscript.py and both shell scripts all need to consume a separate argument list, your command line would look something like this:

```
python runscript.py <args for runscript> -- <args for 1st script> -- <args for 2nd script>
```

For example (I'm just guessing at your hierarchy):

```
python runscript.py -O start -- -l test -p maim -- -f/dev/sda1 -b256k -Q8
```